# blaze.js Uncaught Error: Can't render undefined

Tags: meteor

Using ongoworks:pdf Meteor package to save pdf file on client.

The function:

```
"click #button_export": function(ev, template) {
    var content = document.getElementById("printData").innerHTML;
    Blaze.saveAsPDF(Template.report, {
        filename: bomId + ".pdf",
        data: content,
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        orientation: "landscape",
        unit: "in",
        format: "letter"
    });
},
```

Error:

> blaze.js?hash=38069f4…:2218 Uncaught Error: Can't render 
>   undefinedcheckRenderContent @ blaze.js?hash=38069f4…:2218contentAsFunc
>   @ blaze.js?hash=38069f4…:2261Blaze.toHTMLWithData @
>   blaze.js?hash=38069f4…:2380Blaze.outputAsPDF @
>   ongoworks_pdf.js?hash=245293c…:9442Blaze.saveAsPDF @
>   ongoworks_pdf.js?hash=245293c…:9461clickButton_export

Comment: Please format your question.

Comment: have you tried: 
// Opens the document in the current window/tab
Blaze.outputAsPDF(Template.report, 'datauri');

Comment: Also check this thread:
https://forums.meteor.com/t/which-package-do-you-use-to-generate-pdfs-in-meteor/3391

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you copied this piece of code from `meteor-pdf`'s example. Was your template named `report`? Otherwise `Template.report` is an non-existent value (`undefined`).

Also, the `content` variable should contains an object (key=>value pairs) to be fed into the specified template (`report`) instead of the HTML string.